# new classes in for loop

Tags: c#, .net, class

Currently I have the following code:

```
        DecisionVariable[] attributes = 
        {
            new DecisionVariable("Var1", 2),
            new DecisionVariable("Var2", 4),
            new DecisionVariable("Var3", 1),
            new DecisionVariable("Var4", 2),
            new DecisionVariable("Var5", 5),
        };
```

but I would like to create them using a For loop:

```
        DecisionVariable[] attributes = 
        {
            for (int i=0;i<49;i++)
            {
                new DecisionVariable ("Var" + i, iValues[i]);
            }
        };
```

In the second version C# tells me that "For" has an invalid expression.

Do I have a typo somewhere or is something like that generally not allowed, using a for loop in a constructor?

Comment: Thats because you have your foor loop in initializer.

Comment: Initialize array first and after that do a for loop to add items in the array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use a `for` loop inside a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use this code instead:

```
DecisionVariable[] attributes = new DecisionVariable[49];
for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
    attributes[i] = new DecisionVariable ("Var" + i, iValues[i]);
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer than. While I love `LINQ` and `Range` method, the style of simple `for` loop looks fine

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: I am a huge fan of LINQ, but it's not always the right tool for the job.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, could you please explain **why not** use LINQ to generate this array?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov: No need to explain. You need to explain why I should use LINQ in this scenario. The loop is (1) less code and (2) very easy to read and understand. So why should I use LINQ instead? A third point would be performance, because LINQ adds a little overhead. But that's actually not the reason why I chose the loop. The little overhead of LINQ in this scenario most likely wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, counterarguments: (1) not sure about "less code" (my code is just **one line longer**), (2) `Enumerable.Range()` is **less error-prone** than `for`-loop. (3) there is a **very-very little overhead** of LINQ for this case.

Comment: @SergeyBrunov: (1) one line longer is *still* longer. That's not a problem per-se, but there are no other good reasons why the longer version should be used. (2) I doubt it. And your comment on Yakimych's answer proves me right. (3) Agreed, and that's what I already said in my last comment: It was not part of my decision to not use LINQ. **Conclusion:** I simply see no advantage in using LINQ in this scenario.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, okay, I think it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @SergeyBrunov: Indeed. And I actually upvoted your answer for its second part. Because in that scenario I would also use LINQ.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, thank you! It was a good discussion. Glad we understand each other.

Answer (score 3):

```
    DecisionVariable[] attributes = new DecisionVariable[49];  

    for (int i=0; i<49; i++)
    {
        attributes[i] = new DecisionVariable("Var" + i, iValues[i]);
    }
```

You could also use `generics` and do:

```
   List<DecisionVariable> attributes = new List<DecisionVariable>();

    for (int i=0; i<49; i++)
    {
        attributes.Add(new DecisionVariable("Var" + i, iValues[i]));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ syntax to do this:

```
DecisionVariable[] attributes = 
                      Enumerable.
                      Range(0, 49).
                      Select(i => new DecisionVariable("Var" + i, iValues[i])).
                      ToArray();
```

Comment: Note: the second parameter of `Range()` is **count** (not end value).

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to use [Enumerable.Range Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx):

```
DecisionVariable[] attributes = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 49)
    .Select(i => new DecisionVariable("Var" + i, iValues[i]))
    .ToArray();
```

If the `iValues` array has **the same number of elements** you would like to have for the `attributes` array then consider the following code:

```
DecisionVariable[] decisionVariables = iValues
    .Select((value, index) => new DecisionVariable("Var" + index, value))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Your second query will not return the same result, but rather be ordered the same way as the `iValues` array (nothing an `OrderBy` wouldn't take care of ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Class1[] c1 = new Class1[12];
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
       c1[i] = new Class1(i);
}
```